# Dynamically assigning numbers to an array in C

Tags: c

I want to do this:

```
char a[5];

//run some code here
//then

a[]={0,1,2,3,4};  //**compiler doesn't like it
```

but I don't want to do this:

```
a[0]=0;
a[1]=1;
a[2]=2;
a[3]=3;
a[4]=4;
```

Do you know any way to populate an array at run time with numbers, not a string (i.e., not `a ="hello"`), in one go, instead of defining every element individually?

Thanks,

Raed

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way of doing that. You need to use a loop, or assign each value individually.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* set up a template to be copied into it later:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char a_src[] = {0,10,20,30,40};
int main() {
    char a[5];

    memcpy (a, a_src, sizeof(a_src));
    printf ("%d\n", a[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs 30 when run.

But this is still techically sourcing the data at compile-time. If you *really* want to do it at runtime (with calculated values), you need to do it element by element.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a[5];

//run some code here
//then

static const char a_01234[sizeof(a)] = {0,1,2,3,4};
memcpy(a, a_01234, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do `memcpy(a, "\0\1\2\3\4", 5);`, but it's bad practice and coding style.

Short of that no you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
char a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

The compiler will automatically set this to be an array of 5, initialized with each element corresponding to their value and index.

***Edit:***
Looking at it again, I realized what you were looking for. In short the compiler will not accept this.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pointer and reference it as an array.

```
char * a;
char b[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
char c[5] = {5,6,7,8,9};

//run some code here
//then

a = b;  // "Populate" the "array"

// Then reference a using array notation
printf ("%d\n", a[3]);  // Print the number 3

// run some more code

a = c;  // "Populate the "array" with some new values
printf ("%d\n", a[3]);  // Print the number 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C99 compound literals (supported by GCC but not MSVC),

```
char a[5];

//run some code here
//then

memcpy(a, (char[]){0,1,2,3,4}, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score -2):

sprintf( a, "%d%d%d%d%d", 0,1,2,3,4 );

Changed my answer.

Comment: If you're going to do this, declare a as `char a[6]` - you need an extra byte for the NULL character strcpy will append.

Comment: Your new answer requires the extra byte as well.

Comment: It also puts 48 in instead of 0: %d prints the ASCII value. You could probably fix this (and the extra byte problem) with: `snprintf(a,5,"%c%c%c%c%c",0,1,...`, but I'm not suggesting it's a good idea.  Stick with memcpy, a loop or individual assignment.

Comment: @fixmedaily: This doesn't do anything near what the OP wants.